# Can you recommend an in-browser Ruby/Rails 3D renderer?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rendering

I want to draw some 3D network diagrams in a web browser, and the data for these diagrams are in a Rails app (in the database).

I already use [flotomatic](http://github.com/xdotcommer/flotomatic) as a Rails interface for pretty Javascript plots (e.g., independent variable, dependent variable). Certainly there are packages for drawing simple things in Javascript.

What I'm looking for is (a) a Javascript package for 3D drawings that are displayed in a web browser (without a plugin), and (b) a Ruby API for that package, if possible.

Any recommendations? Many thanks!

Comment: What kind of 3D drawings are you talking about?

Comment: Pretty basic stuff. Lines, maybe primitives, doesn't really need shading. It's for network diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a definitive answer, but something like this might be useful:

- http://www.canvasdemos.com/2009/04/05/processingjs/
- http://processingjs.org/

In short, processing has been ported to javascript and makes use of the HTML5 canvas element.

Processing.js [does not yet support 3D](http://processingjs.org/reference/articles/comparing-processing) (as canvas doesn't support it due to lack of acceleration), but it shouldn't be a big deal to create a wireframe.